# Careers RSS feed not limiting to 'telecommute'

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, feed

Using Google Reader I track a Careers RSS feed which searches for "linux cisco" and limits it to telecommute jobs. However the feed contains ads for non-telecommute roles.

Feed URL is http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?searchTerm=linux+cisco&range=20&istelecommute=true

e.g. this role ended up in the feed http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/14716/senior-software-engineer-ign-entertainment

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing the issue at the moment. It's possible that the employer who posted the job changed the telecommute setting. Let us know if it recurs.

Comment: Checking Google reader just now none of the 8 new posts in the RSS feed are telecommute. They are http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/15056/sr-c-plus-plus-network-programmer-waterfront-international /jobs/15059/senior-hadoop-developer-quantcast /jobs/15072/software-support-engineer-onalytica /jobs/15071/senior-developer-search-and-advertising-synacor /jobs/15068/systemutvecklare-som-tror-p%C3%A5-en-uppkopplad-v%C3%A4rld-cybercom-group /jobs/15080/java-developer-investor-analytics /jobs/15085/senior-developer-client-integrations-synacor /jobs/15084/devops-infrastructure-engineer-surveymonkey